# Sneaking up on a bug?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

So, I am trying to catch some bugs I have not done so before and the ones that fly out of the trees have eluded me to this point (I am not sure what they are called as I have not caught them).

Some times I bump a tree and a bug will fly out really quickly, other times I just walk by them. In both cases however even if I have my net out already its too late. I have taken to sneaking from tree to tree and smacking it with my net but so far this has yielded nothing.

How can I catch the bugs that just fly out of the branches so fast? (Not the spider, the spider is easy :))

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, sneaking up on bugs in New Leaf works better when you:

- "Stop-and-go" sneak.  Continuous movement near tree-class bugs will scare them off.  Sneak, and then stop if you see any change in the bug's behavior.  (i.e. if the bug is moving, and then suddenly stops, or vise-versa)
- Approach from the front of the tree.  I have much less success if I try to wrap around the tree from behind.  I only have anecdotal evidence to support this, but bugs I have attempted to catch seem to fly away more often when I'm not approaching from the front.
- Probably obvious, but don't bump the tree or make any environmental noises.  Approaching palm trees from the beach waves seems to tip the bugs off to your presence, for example.
- Don't get too close.  Being just outside the front shadow of the tree is usually enough to make a swing at the bugs.
- Sneak as soon as you're aware of a bug's presence.  Extremely rare bugs, such as the Golden Stag, will fly away as soon as their tree enters the screen if you are not sneaking correctly.  This is easy to practice on the island, where you can cycle through tree bugs quickly every evening after 7pm.

As I mentioned in the list above, a good place to practice your sneaking is the tropical island.  My advice for the island is to strip your island of most (if not all) normal trees, and all flowers, leaving only palm trees.  This is because normal trees and flowers will spawn bugs that are worth less than bugs that will spawn on palm trees.  It will also spawn bugs that don't require sneaking to catch, which would be impractical for this exercise.

For easier bug catching, I also recommend that you cut down all palm trees that aren't on the left, right, and back of your island with respect to the camera.  Something like this:

```
OOHOO
O|||O
O|||O
O|||O
XXXXX
```

Legend:

- H - Island Hut
- O - Beaches.  Leave palm trees on these beaches.
- | - Grassy Island Area.  Remove trees and flowers from this area, unless you want to catch deciduous tree bugs.
- X - Front beach wrt camera.  Remove trees here, because you have to wrap around the tree to catch these bugs.

Bugs that spawn on palm trees all have a very high sell-value, and you can practice sneaking on them without damaging your village.  Setting your island up in this manner will ensure that only palm tree bugs, wharf roaches, and hermit crabs will spawn on your island.

Comment: Are the bugs even visible? I always just thought they flew out but have not found a way to tell they are there as of yet. This kind of seems like 'Just keep sneaking up on random trees' as the overall answer to me, hehe. I should also mention I am not to the Island yet.. I am just in my town.

Comment: Bugs that appear on trees should always be visible until they have been scared off, at which point they will either fly away or fade out (in the case of the walking stick).  They aren't incredibly common during the day in June, but you can visit your island in the evening (after 7pm) and find many, many tree bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the A button down and walk. You'll sneak and as soon as you let go of the A button you will use your net.